# divide two binary Long division, Binary division algorithm

Tags: javascript, binary

I am trying to implement Long division [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm).
But I faced some problems.
[image]

If we take N=1100 and D=100

`Step 1: Set R=0 and Q=0 Step 2: Take i=3 (one less than the number of bits in N) Step 3: R=00 (left shifted by 1) Step 4: R=01 (setting R(0) to N(i))`

how did we get '01'
on fourth step, if n[3] = 0 from N = 1100

I tried to code program, but I can't understand the fourth step.

```js
        n = "1100";
        d = "0100";

        let q = "0";
        let r = "0";

        for (let i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
          r = r + "0"; //0 + 0 = "00"
          r[0] = n[i];

          if (r >= d) {
            r = String(r - d);
            q[i] = 1;
          }
        }

        console.log(q);
        console.log(r);
```

We use Q as result of '1' but if result of division is '101' where did we take '0' from r?

Comment: I was wrong about editing string as index.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous data type issues with the way you've written the algorithm.  The following are some helpful tips to assist you in your endeavor...

- All the binary values are written in Big Endian, whereas the for loop is written expecting Little Endian.
- The line `r[0] = n[i]` is not doing what you think.  Try a simple experiment as follows, and you will see that x does not change as expected...

  ```js
  x = "abcd"
  x[3] = "e"
  console.log( x )    // x is still "abcd"
  ```
- The line `if (r >= d)` is performing a string comparison rather than numeric comparison.  This will lead to erroneous results.  For example, consider...

  ```js
  console.log( "11" >= "01111" )
  console.log( parseInt( "11", 2 ) >= parseInt( "01111", 2 ) )
  ```
- The line `r = String(r - d)` is attempting to substract 2 strings which Javascript will attempt to coerce to *decimal* Numbers, unless the strings are preceded by "0b" in which case the coercion will interpret the strings as binary numbers.

  ```js
  console.log( 'abcd' - 'efghi' )       // NaN
  console.log( '1100' - '0100' )        // Decimal result of one thousand.
  console.log( '0b1100' - '0b0100' )    // Proper binary result of 8 (0b1000).
  ```
- The line `q[i] = 1` suffers the same issue as noted in the second bullet.

Comment: thanks for tips. I used method to copy string and a function to paste zeros at beggining to compare numbers.